# How to set the Ipv6 vor a domain without subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

In my DNS setup, I set a record for

```
* 138.my.ip.here
```

this works for `spacetrace.org` as for `www.spacetrace.org`

Now I tried the same with an AAAA record for IPv6:

```
* 2a01:4f8:171:27a2:0:77:77:101
```

but this seems only work for all subdomains, including `www`, but not the main domain.

I used this check: https://ip6.nl/#!spacetrace.org

How do I set this right for the main domain?

This is my entry so far:

[image]

Comment: At a guess, you're being downvoted because you don't show the actual relevant lines from the zone file. Also because you've not noticed that there's a separate A record for the apex, in addition to the wildcard record.

Comment: what is "a separate A record for the apex"? I found out, that there is an entry in my domain hosters dns interface with an `@` sign. I thought that this is for the case, that someone uses an url like http://user@spacetrace.org , but maybe that is the entry for the domain itself? What more output do aou need from my server?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the record for the domain itself - also known as the apex of the zone file. You need to add one like it but with the AAAA record. Though since you're using your provider's custom web interface, it's hard for me to be certain. And your question will probably be closed, again because you're not managing your DNS zone yourself.

Comment: I think the downvotes are from the time, the additional data was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a separate AAAA record for "apex":

```
@ 2a01:4f8:171:27a2:0:77:77:101
```

This is represented by an `@` (at-sign) in the DNS-Interface.

> An apex record is one at the root of a DNS zone. Sometimes called "naked domains".